# Shorten the code without a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I want to check if the number is present in the column `col` and run a `mysqli_num_rows`. So far its working with the following code:

```
//$conn = connection to mysql.

$row1sql = "SELECT * from chktable where col='1'";
$row2sql = "SELECT * from chktable where col='2'";
$row3sql = "SELECT * from chktable where col='3'";
$row4sql = "SELECT * from chktable where col='4'";

$query1sql = $conn->query($row1sql);
$query2sql = $conn->query($row2sql);
$query3sql = $conn->query($row3sql);
$query4sql = $conn->query($row4sql);

$num1 = mysqli_num_rows($query1sql);    
$num2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2sql);    
$num3 = mysqli_num_rows($query3sql);    
$num4 = mysqli_num_rows($query4sql);
```

I edit the other code based on the `$num`.

How can I shorten this code? Can I use a `for` statement? How do I use it if its applicable? Or any other way to shorten this code?

Thanks.

Comment: how about you have no for, just 1 query, a while, and process them. [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I suggest using a prepared statement and executing it with the various values. See [prepared statements @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @showdev i have no experience with prepd stmts. am looking for something with raw php.

Comment: SELECT count(*) as br, col from chktable where col in('1','2','3','4');
you can get it with one query

Comment: I don't think the examples on that page are any less "raw" than the code you've posted. Something to consider anyway.

Comment: Depending on your context (e.g. amount of data), I like the idea of a single query. Maybe something like `SELECT \`col\`,COUNT(*) as \`count\` FROM \`chktable\` GROUP BY \`col\``?

Comment: @Drew I dont see how this is a `XY Problem` mate. I am trying to shorten the code. I mentioned the current code does work. So X is working and not failing. I never mentioned about Y (while loop) but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You just accepted an answer, the one I suggested in the comment, saying do 1 query and a `while loop`, and that it was XY. If you understand and read that, it means when someone presents a question like yours, saying, I have a Problem (`X`),  please write this in a `for` loop for me (`Y`). I spot it as an `XY`, The `Y` is not what you should do. So let's go focus back on X (the problem). You ought to read it. And thx for confirming it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the col value and number of rows of it, only for col values 1,2,3,4

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT col, count(*) as num FROM chktable GROUP BY col WHERE col IN (1,2,3,4);");
while($row = $query->fetch_object())
    echo "Col: ".$row->col.", Num:".$row->num;
```

you can do whatever check you want inside the while loop

Comment: Im getting: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in...`. I did add `{ }` after the while loop & tried without that too. Checking wht im missing. appreciate any help please

Comment: `SELECT col, count(*) as num FROM chktable WHERE col IN (1,2,3,4) GROUP BY col` this worked. But how do i know the value of the columns. Sorry if im missing something. How can i find the value of $num1 or $num2?

Comment: I got it. Thanks a ton mate!